# Access Gmail Inbox using libcurl in C++

Tags: c++, email, libcurl

I am writing a program which can access gmail account of a user and then show unread emails.
I am not sure what url should I use for

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"urlhere")
```

I am asking this after reading this question

[SMTP mail using libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809693/smtp-mail-using-libcurl)

I have already tried writing "mail.google.com" , it didn't work.

According to link here

http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_POP3_Settings.htm

`Gmail POP server address: pop.gmail.com`
`Gmail POP port: 995`

So I tried

```
 "pop3://pop.gmail.com:995"
```

but it returns CURLE_RECV_ERROR which says that 
"Failure when recieving Data from the peer".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"smtp://mail.google.com")
```

[curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

Comment: CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM and CURLOPT_URL are tow different properties.. how is it related here?

Answer (score 0):

See Google's documentation for [Gmail access through IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview). Apparently, you should use `imap.gmail.com:993` for IMAP connection.

Comment: by default pop is enabled while imap is disabled in gmail.